# Get Instagram Stories through hashtag or mention?

Tags: instagram, fetch, virtualization

Need some assistance in where to start looking. Is there a workaround with using an official API or tips for virtualizing Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

I think below Instagram API endpoint could help you:

```
"feed/tag/{tag!s}/"
```

Personally, I am using Instagram Private API and I think it is super cool. 
(https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#instagram_private_api.Client.feed_tag)

```
username = "XXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXX"
hashtag = "football"

api = Client(username, password)
tag_metadata = api.feed_tag(hashtag, api.generate_uuid())
football_stories = tag_metadata["story"]["items"]

for story in football_stories: 
    # Do whatever you want with the story.
    print story
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Do you know how to paginate between all stories?
Every call returns the same 20 results.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Instagram API endpoints which could help you, such as:

```
"feed/user/{$userId}/reel_media/" 

"feed/reels_tray/"
```